# From HTML into Jade format

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I would like to ask for help in converting from HTML format into Jade format this small piece of code. I kinda have an idea how Jade works, but i have problems in understanding how to act with "%" signs over her.

I would really appreciate your help (:

extends layout

```
<ul class="messages">
  <% for(var i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {%>
    <li class="messages">

      <span><%=" Message: " + messages[i].content%></span>

    </li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop for en jade is an iteration `each`

```
ul.message
    each val, index in messages
        li.messages
            span= index + ': ' + val
```

Consult the [jade doc](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html) for more info

Comment: It gives me this error: SyntaxError: C:\Users\Edgaras\Desktop\passport-local-express4-master\views\getMessages.jade:6
    4| ul.message
    5|     each val, index in messages
  > 6|         li.messages= 
    7|             span= index + ': ' + val 

Unexpected token )